# ggplot2 plot executing correctly in Rstudio but not getting displayed in knitr html

Tags: r

I am facing a strange issue. Have written a code with ggplot2 which is getting executed perfectly in Rstudio and the plots are getting displayed.But when i am trying to publish into html using knitr the output plots are not getting displayed. I have tried print() to display and it is still not working.

I have tried reinstalling Rstudio as well.

```
{r,include=TRUE,echo=TRUE,eval=FALSE}
meandaytype<- 
aggregate(analysis1$steps,by=list(analysis1$Daytype,analysis1$interval),mean)
names(meandaytype)[1]<-"Daytype"
names(meandaytype)[2]<-"Interval"
names(meandaytype)[3]<-"steps"
p<-ggplot(meandaytype,aes(x=Interval,y= steps,color=Daytype)) + 
geom_line()+facet_grid(Daytype~.)+labs(title="Mean steps per inteval and day 
type",x="Interval",y="MeanSteps")
print(p)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using version 1.1.447

Comment: what happens if you use `eval = TRUE` instead?

Comment: Like @Nate pointed out, `eval=FALSE` means the chunk isn't evaluated when you knit the file

Comment: With eval = TRUE i am getting an error while converting it to html "Error in eval: could not find function "ggplot"->evel execution halted"